# Windows auth in aspnet core is unpredictable using IISExpress or HttpSys

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, iis-express

In my asp.net core web app I need to find a login name for the user making a request. This is done in the middleware using a name claim from HttpContext.

```
public static string GetUserName(HttpContext ctx)
{
    var claim = ctx.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (claim != null)
        return claim.Value;

    claim = ctx.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

    var arr = claim?.Value.Split('\\');
    return arr?[arr.Length - 1];
}
```

But **sometimes** Context.User.UserClaims is empty. It looks like this mostly happens when multiple requests come almost at the same time. For some of those requests claims are empty and for some they are not.

It never happens to me under IIS but does happen under IISExpress and HttpSys. I hope someone has an idea why it behaves this way.

Here's my launch.json

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": true,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
            "sslPort": 0
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "use64Bit": true
        },
        "HttpSys": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "launchBrowser": false,
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is why is that happening. It should always have a user name claim.

Comment: User names should be queried in your controller, via `ControllerBase.User`. You should not expect the HTTP context object to always give you the user, and that also applies to classic ASP.NET 4.x.

Comment: I don't need it at the controller level. I need it to be available for every single request. And it works just fine under IIS. But not in Express.